# How to determine that SQL Server is really lacking memory

Tags: sql-server

We're running SQL Server Express for our project. I'm trying to prove that we have to move to Standard or Web version of it. Just because I suspect that because of Express edition limitation it can't use as much of RAM as it needs. When I look at SQL Server process in the process explorer I always see that it utilizes around 1.5 gigs of RAM and never goes higher.

Is there a tool which will allow me to tell that the maximum memory amount it can use is really the issue?

**Update**. We're using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit). Results of DBCC are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzrue9hzhcb5unj/dbcc_results.txt?dl=0). Maximum allowed amount of memory is 4 gigabytes.

Comment: What is the version of SQL server? How much is the RAM allocated on box? What are you're max and min server memory? Also can you share the output of DBCC MEMORYSTATUS

Comment: There are [lots](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49420/sql-server-how-to-determine-ideal-memory-for-instance?rq=1) of [similar](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46168/sql-server-not-using-available-memory?rq=1) questions that [may help](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33970/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-sql-server-queries-are-running-in-memory-or-going?rq=1) you.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: First clear what version of SQL Server you are using. With express edition you have limitation of memory from 2012 onwards SQL Server database engine can only use around 1.5 G not more than that. This is well documented https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2663912 see the last paragraph

Comment: Here is a good start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/monitor-memory-usage?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if SQL Server is memory constrained by monitoring the Page Life Expectancy perfmon counter. Monitor it over time and if this counter is consistently low you probably have memory pressure.

you could also query the ring buffer as described in https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/identifying-external-memory-pressure-with-dm_os_ring_buffers-and-ring_buffer_resource_monitor/.

Comment: That is what I meant, fixed it.

Comment: [Page Life Expectancy isn’t what you think…](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/page-life-expectancy-isnt-what-you-think/)